# How to cd to a directory whose name starts with 2.* ?, directory name can be 2.1 or 2.6 or 2.anything

Tags: python-3.x

os.chdir('/home/apadwal/Desktop/2.*') does not work.
The folder name can be 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, or 2.anyNumber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming either there is always going to be only one directory in the specified parent directory whose name starts with `2.`, or it doesn't matter which one of the many matching directories to cd into, you can cd into the first directory generated by `glob.iglob` instead:

```
from glob import iglob
import os
for d in iglob('/home/apadwal/Desktop/2.*'):
    os.chdir(d)
    break
else:
    print('No matching directory found.')
```

Comment: os.chdir(glob.glob('/home/apadwal/Desk*/2.*')[0])